# Is there a way or how to predict the output size as a result of encryption?

Tags: encryption, output-size

Is there a way or how to predict the output size as a result of encryption from 3DES, AES-128, AES-192 etc ? So that I know how to store them in the data in DB given a known possible clear text length.

Comment: It's just a form of transcoding.  What makes you think that it's not entirely predictable?

Comment: These algorithms alone don't specify any header or block mode of operation. You should be more specific about what exact tool you are using. For example AES works by taking input blocks of 128 bits, 192 bits and transcoding them in resulting blocks of 128 bits or 192 bits. Alone, it doesn't handle data length not multiple of 128 or 192.

Comment: @KrisWebDev: AES primitive (ECB) always uses data 128; the key may be 128 192 256. (Nonstandardized) Rijndael supports other data sizes, and other key sizes as well.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on:

1. Precise choice of encryption algorithm
2. Choice of representation for the ciphertext
3. Size of additional metadata stored with each ciphertext

On #1, 3DES, AES128, AES192 are block ciphers, so they're not ready-to-use end-user variable message length encryption algorithms.  You use them in the context of some **mode**, which you should really think of the "real" encryption algorithm.  For example, one very common mode nowadays is [GCM (Galois Counter Mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), which instantiated with AES we would call AES-GCM.  Some modes require ciphertexts to be a multiple of the block cipher block size as well, which means that plaintexts get padded to fill up a block.

So first and foremost, the size of a ciphertext depends on the mode.  AES-GCM ciphertexts, in binary, are generally 16 bytes longer than the plaintexts.  And you may need an additional 12 bytes to store the [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

Now, #2 ("choice of representation for the ciphertext"): ciphers operate on **binary data** and produce **binary output**.  But many systems and developers are very allergic to binary data and prefer all data to be in some sort of plain-text format (e.g., XML, JSON).  So the raw binary output of a cipher is in practice often encoded into ASCII using a binary-to-text encoding like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  This adds about a 33% overhead over raw binary size.

Point #3 ("size of additional metadata stored with each ciphertext"): Often you want to store additional information with each ciphertext, for example metadata related to **key management**:

- A **key identifier** that allows you to locate, for each ciphertext, the key that was used to encrypt it.
- An encrypted **data encryption key** (DEK).  This is part of a common key management strategy where ciphertexts are encrypted with an ephemeral DEK key, which is then encrypted with a master key (a key encryption key or KEK), and the encrypted DEK is stored alongside the ciphertext.

So you need to work out a number of details to get a precise answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you Luis for the good points you have layout. I do know I am using CFB mode for 3DES and AES family from openssl.  I should state more clearly the output as  byte length right after encryption. Once I know the byte length, I know how to calculate base64 length and stored in DB.  Of course there are factor you mentioned above. However, currently, I am interested to know the output of byte length.

Comment: I found there are good information talks about ciphertext size:  http://www.obviex.com/articles/CiphertextSize.pdf ( from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283787/size-of-data-after-aes-cbc-and-aes-ecb-encryption)

Comment: @wei3923: that answer implies padding is required which it is not for CFB, although preferably you should have an IV which is canonically but not necessarily a full block. And be careful: CFB can have different feedback sizes which doesn't affect ciphertext expansion, but if you use a non-matching one it will totally bollix your decryption and effectively destroy your data.